# SVN modified current directory and empty name file

Tags: svn

I tried to add one of my folders to ignore using `svn propset svn:ignore folder/mysubfolder .` I then ended up with a mysterious unnamed file that SVN does not recognize. There is also a strange space before the M on the current directory caused by the setprop command.

```
root@myhost:/srv# svn status
 M      .
?
A       myfile.txt
?       folder/mysubfolder
```

What does this empty name file mean? Where does it come from and how to I get rid of it safely?

Comment: Did you copy&paste your example all at once, i.e. is the first question mark really immediately followed by newline?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange space before the M is not strange at all; it's just a status message in the second column which tells you that the SVN properties in the current directory have changed, in this case it refers to the change you made to the property svn:ignore.

By the way, your `folder/mysubfolder` is not getting ignored, as you can see from the ? in the status message. You should have edited the svn:ignore property of `folder`, like this:

```
svn propset svn:ignore mysubfolder folder
```

Or, if you have previously modified its svn:ignore property, you can edit it:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore folder
```

You may also wish to revert the property change in the current directory since it is not taking any effect.

```
svn revert .
```

I'm not sure what the ? for the blank file name is. Try to see if `ls -l` reveals any more information

Comment: Thanks. It seems the empty space filename was actually a directory that had been created with the name " ".

Comment: Cool, glad you sorted it out